# What is .NET framework backward compatibility?

Tags: .net, backward-compatibility

We develop a windows application in .NET 4 with a database of MySQL. When we are about to deploy that application, we install the .NET 4 framework in our client, then when installing the .NET Connector for MySQL, it requires a .NET framework 3.5. But the .NET 4 is already installed. Wasn't .NET framework backward compatible?

We end up installing two .NET framework (3.5 & 4) which isn't small in disk size. What exactly does backward compatibility means?

Comment: The answer to the unasked question: yes, it's okay to be angry.

Comment: Do you have to install the whole .NET 3.5 Framework for one connector? Did you try to copy / register only required assemblies?

Comment: `What is .NET framework backward compatibility?` A myth.

Comment: @YannisRizos They hold the obsolete codes/functionality and keep their framework larger and larger for a myth? .NET is weird.

Comment: @ErikReppen: angry against whom?

Comment: @DocBrown: Very large design team strategies. I kid. Well, 3 years ago I wouldn't be kidding but MS has been shaping up quite a bit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To quote [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx):

> The .NET Framework 4 is backward-compatible with applications that
>   were built with the .NET Framework versions 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5. In
>   other words, applications and components built with previous versions
>   of the .NET Framework will work on the .NET Framework 4.
>
> However, in practice, this compatibility can be broken by seemingly
>   inconsequential changes in the .NET Framework and changes in
>   programming techniques. For example, performance improvements in the
>   .NET Framework 4 can expose a race condition that did not occur on
>   earlier versions. Similarly, using a hard-coded path to .NET Framework
>   assemblies, performing an equality comparison with a particular
>   version of the .NET Framework, and getting the value of a private
>   field by using reflection are not backward-compatible practices. In
>   addition, each version of the .NET Framework includes bug fixes and
>   security-related changes that can affect the compatibility of some
>   applications and components.
>
> You should test your .NET Framework applications and components to
>   ensure that they are compatible with other versions of the .NET
>   Framework. To ensure that an application or component successfully
>   runs on the .NET Framework 4, use the .NET Framework 4 Application
>   Compatibility Walkthrough.

You may also see this *very useful* thread wherein a detailed explanation was given:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816914/backwards-compatibility-of-net-framework-4

Answer (score 3):

Looking at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net-versions.html, I guess you don't need version 3.5, version 2.0 should be enough (which is much smaller and part of 3.5).

If nothing else helps, you could try to compile the connector by yourself against FW 4.0, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net-installation-source.html